# Magento2: Products lists images - very poor quality

Tags: magento2, product-images

example: on products list is "small image". on product page is "base  image".

a) on the products list  "small image" products in one line  the quality is very poor due to large size image

Please see on example below watch. This both screen is from mobile.

1. Small image in products list   2.Screen from gallery product from product page

https://ibb.co/SJWHJM9

The difference is very big.

We use imagemagic. Maybe anyone have some idea how to get the same quality photo in the product list as in "gallery product". ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For product list pages you can use the large images by creating a view.xml file in your custom theme with the following code.
File path

```
/app/design/frontend/YOURVENDORNAME/YOURTHEMENAME/etc/view.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
<media>
    <images module="Magento_Catalog">
        <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
            <width>700</width>
            <height>700</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
            <width>700</width>
            <height>700</height>
        </image>
    </images>
</media>
</view>
```

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but you will get large images on category pages or product list pages using this method.